# Decoding a binary raster GIS file: Vertical Mapper .grd

Tags: matlab, binary, gis, raster, mapper

Does anyone know of a method to decode this sort binary file. It should have a quite simple structure, a couple of lines of headers and then just grid data. I have the Vertical Mapper software but I want to cut out a step in my modelling process and do everything in matlab??

Any tips are appreciated.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the [Mapping Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/mapping/) for that.